# How to acknowledge a .net request in the middle of a SQL Query execution so that the time out exception doesn't raise

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a asp.net mvc application which is used to validate the data that is in the database using a SQL Server stored procedure. If the data is over a million records, it takes more than 40 minutes to process them and gives the validation results back to the .net mvc application. I have programmed such a way to sustain the .net mvc application browser session for one hour. But after 20 minutes a time out exception is being raised, as there won't be any response from the sql server until it finishes the SP processing. Is there any way to hold the session of sql server response call in .net mvc? or can I send any acknowledgements from sql in the middle of Stored Procedure call process?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can raise all timeouts that are involved here. Identify what component caused a timeout (ADO.NET or ASP.NET) and adjust the value.

The problem with that is that 40min long HTTP requests are quite unreliable. Any temporary problem such as a small network disruption or a router terminating idle connections can kill the connection. Also, you will sometimes need to restart the server (deployments, reboots, crashes).

This is not a good architecture.

Maybe you can split the work into smaller parts of, say, 10 seconds?

Comment: I get this problem on https(SSL) only, but not on http if the .net mvc application browser operation is in the same network as of the application and db server.

Comment: So? Did you consider doing what I recommend in my answer? Your comment does not relate to the answer.

Comment: No, I can not split the work into smaller parts...all my validations are inter dependent. They had to be run on a single stretch.

Comment: OK, then at least run the work on the server in a background thread (e.g. Task.Run) and notify the client when the work is done (e.g. using SignalR). That way network connection problems are solved. This is much better.

Comment: I thought of doing it as the last option, I am just inquiring if there are any other settings that has to be done to make it run for now, until I convert this to a background process.

Comment: You have not said or determined what kind of system has caused the timeout. That's why I say: "Identify what component caused a timeout (ADO.NET or ASP.NET) and adjust the value." Have you done that?